# Graphene and SQLAlchemy: derivate from a base object type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-sqlalchemy

I am building an app using Flask, Graphene, SQLAlchemy and Graphene-SQLAlchemy in which I implemented the following models:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    email = Column(Text, nullable=False)

class BusinessUser(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "bis_user"
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True)
    vatNumber = Column(Text, nullable=False)

class LVUser(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "lv_user"
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True)
    lv_num = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

My goal would be to have three GraphQL types defined as such:

```
type User {
    id : ID
    name : String
    email : String
}

type BusinessUser {
    id : ID
    name : String
    email : String
    vatNumber : String
}

type LVUser {
    id : ID
    name : String
    email : String
    lvNum : Integer
}
```

But I'm struggling to find an efficient and elegant manner of doing so. Is there any way to have, let's say a "base" object type `User` and create `BusinessUser` and `LVUser` types on the top of my base type whilst providing the extra fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [Composing Mapped Hierarchies with Mixins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html) which seems to describe exactly the scenario and solution to what you are looking for.

However, from the fact that you have foreign keys to `user.id` from other two tables hints me an inheritance which can be implemented using [Mapping Class Inheritance Hierarchies](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html), whereas the strategy will depend on how your actual tables on the database level are designed.

Comment: Thanks, that was spot on!
I solved my problem using inheritance, as described in the link you provided.